# Delete from two tables using one SQL query

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using these SQL queries to delete rows from two tables:

```
DELETE FROM AGENT WHERE ID = ?

DELETE FROM AGENT WHERE AGENT_GROUP_ID = (SELECT ID FROM AGENT_GROUP WHERE NAME = ?)
```

I'm interested can I somehow combine the two SQL queries into one SQL query?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
DELETE FROM AGENT 
 WHERE ID = ?
    OR AGENT_GROUP_ID = (SELECT ID FROM AGENT_GROUP WHERE NAME = ?
```

?

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm#i2112830) you can't delete records from multiple tables simultaneously. As a solution, you can write a stored procedure that will delete records from multiple tables, like this:

```
create procedure delete_from_multiple_tables (
  p_key1 number
, p_key2 varchar2
)
as
begin
  delete table1 where id = p_key1;
  delete table2 where group_id = p_key2;
end delete_from_multiple_tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.. It is the same Table? if yes:

```
DELETE FROM AGENT WHERE AGENT_GROUP_ID = (SELECT ID FROM AGENT_GROUP WHERE NAME = ?) Or ID = ?
```

With diffrent tables:

```
DELETE AGENT, MYTABLE2  
FROM AGENT INNER JOIN MYTABLE2  
WHERE AGENT.id = ?  OR MYTABLE2.id = (Select ID from ...)
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as the previous answer, you didn't bring a new idea

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the SQL queries on different tables.

Comment: @simsim jap.. i didn't saw the answer from zaratustra.. after i postet... oh... too late.. :)
user1285928: ok.. I extended my answer

Comment: @EdiG., that's why I gave you some time before deciding to down-vote your answer

Comment: @EdiG. Oracle doesn't support the syntax you provided for deleting rows from multiple tables simultaneously.

Comment: I forgot to write - this is for Oracle.